# Is there a valve design or system that can do this?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, gas, valves, liquid, fluid-filtration

I am trying to come up with a way to bleed air from a tube to avoid air (gas) from reaching the other end of the tube. Is there a way to do this automatically? It must be able to work in all orientations and it shouldn't leak any fluid when it is shaken or turned upside down. I've thought about trapping air by raising a section of the tube before it reaches the end, sort of like what's pictured here:

[image]

However, this can only last so long until it becomes an air lock and fluid stops flowing, and I didn't think that it could work when it is upside down. Is there a way I could use this concept but continuously remove the gas out of the tube?

A design that could differentiate gas and liquid in a tube and can make them flow in different pathways would be the best solution (if this even exists).

I would appreciate any ideas and concepts that could be used to come up with a design. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I've understood it well you need to vent a water pipe, correct?
Is it an open circuit or a close circuit?
Which is the amount of air at the inlet? Which is the acceptable content of air at the end of the pipe?
Is it a continuous process?

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRVJSGM6kso)

Comment: There are about a brazillion gas - oil separators in oil/gas production. Many designs but all stationary.

Comment: Actually many of them are three phase separations, gas ,oil , and water.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestion guys. I think what I was looking for is kind of like what NMech linked to.